# How to deal with the Floquet multipliers for a second-order ODEs system?

Tags: stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I am interested in the study of the stability of a system via the Floquet multipliers. So, I understand that when I have a first-order ODEs system each of the variables is *of interest*. For instance, if we consider the [Redox oscillation](https://multiflap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/redox_oscillation.html#dos2019), the system is given by:

$\frac{dD_1}{dt}=p-aAD_1-dD_1$

$\frac{dD_2}{dt}=dD_1-eD_2$

$\frac{dR}{dt}=eD_2-qR$

$\frac{dA}{dt}=bIR-aAD_1$

Consequently, each Floquet multiplier can be plotted in the complex plane. So, each variable, i.e., $D_1, D_2, R$, and $A$ will have a corresponding Floquet multiplier to be assessed. Great!

However, I am a little bit confused about how to proceed with the assessment when I have a second-order ODEs system converted into a first-order ODEs system. For instance, let's suppose I have something like:

$\frac{d^2x_1}{dt^2} = a\frac{dx_1}{dt} + b\frac{dx_2}{dt} + c(t)x_1$

$\frac{d^2x_2}{dt^2} = d\frac{dx_2}{dt} + e\frac{dx_1}{dt} + f(t)x_2$

Then, I can introduce new variables (for instance: $z_1, z_2, z_3$, and $z_4$) and reduce the order of my system, but then I will have four equations and consequently four corresponding Floquet multipliers. So, my big question is: *should I assess in the complex plane all four Floquet multipliers corresponding to ($z_1, z_2, z_3$, and $z_4$) or just the two corresponding back to ($x_1$, and $x_2$)?* Does anyone know how to proceed in this case? Any reference (book, paper, etc.)? Most of the examples and works that I found are exploring first-order systems :/